# check local file existence with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to find the right way to check if a file exists in my ionic / angular app.

For now I found this solution using jquery, but I need to avoid Jquery.

Can you help me translate this to Angular ?

```
   var status = url.fileExists();

   String.prototype.fileExists = function () {
    var filename = this.trim();

     var response = jQuery.ajax({
         url: filename,
         type: 'HEAD',
         async: false
     }).status;

    return (response != "200") ? false : true;
};
```

My attempt would be the following, it this "good practice" ?

```
String.prototype.fileExists = function () {
    var filename = this.trim();

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('HEAD', filename, false);
    request.send();
    var response = request.status;

    return (response != "200") ? false : true;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: would make more sense to make a HEAD request

Comment: @charlietfl can you please show the corresponding code ? I just actually to check if the file is here or not.

Answer (score 0):

would that work :

```
.service('UrlExists', ['isPhoneGap', '$http', function(isPhoneGap, $http) { 

    this.newF = function(url){
        $http.get(url)
             .success(function(data, status){
                if(status==200){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
             })
             .error(function(data,status){
                if(status==200){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
             });
    }
}])
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose like this:

```
var status = url.fileExists();

   String.prototype.fileExists = function () {
    var filename = this.trim();

     var response = $http({
         url: filename,
         method: 'HEAD',
         async: false
     }).status;

    return (response != "200") ? false : true;
};
```